# Can I assign to a jade variable from inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I've seen tons of questions the other way around, but can't find one for assigning to.

So, why can I do this:

```
var username = '#{username}';
```

But not this?

```
#{username} = username;
```

Is there a way to assign to jade variables from inside javascript?

Edit: I ended up doing what Bigood suggested and using server and client side cookies, that works great! I followed a guide that I found from here https://stormpath.com/blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-node-dot-js-sessions/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you talking about server-side or client-side JS?

Comment: Client-side. The end goal is to have session unique persistent data for each user that comes to our website and logs into an account.

Comment: Er I guess I should say unique persist data that can be used in jade templates as well as javascript.

Comment: Did you try to store these informations in a cookie, both client and server side ?  passport.js does that pretty well

Comment: Passport.js huh? We built our own authentication Middleware. How would you access said cookie in out jade templates though? I'm not too familiar with how server side cookies function or even how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `#{username} = username` inside Jade, The `#{username}` get replaced with the value of username.

for example, lets say you are passing `username='Jake'` to your jade template. so when you write

```
#{username}= "somethingElse"
```

It actually becomes

```
<Jake> = "somethingElse"</Jake>
```

Thats the reason we cant do that.

Comment: Hmmm...not sure why you were down voted but I up voted you. This is a useful piece of information, thanks!